# Convert types from A to B and vice versa Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

Part of our web services interface we created lighter weight client facing APIs which are not dependent on any specific platform/vendor APIs.

Now impl of those service traits will have to convert these platform agnostic types, that are carrying incoming data, to vendor specific types for impl methods to  continue working as is. Note that we don't have an ability to change any code on vendor APIs. I am thinking we'll have to create some kind of adapter/translation APIs that can do this types conversion both ways. Some of the vendor types are quite cryptic. e.g. lighter weight service interface may have a flatten type that carries all the data, whereas vendor API has hierarchical type that can take input data etc. Same is the case with return types. What would be the best way to do achieve this in Scala?

Edit: Example

```
case class A(var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6)

public Class B{

  private C c;
  private D d;

}
```

case class is a flatten structure with all data needed whereas on the other side data coming from class class A is to be populated into B (var2,var3),C(var4,var5),D(var6) etc. Also I forgot to mention that vendor APIs is all Java based.

Thanks,

Comment: Too broad.  A proper analysis of the issues involved to address your specific situation is well outside the scope of SO.

Comment: Function1[A,B] converts from A to B. Beyond that, I don't know how anyone can answer this question without a more specific description of the computation you're trying to achieve.

Comment: fair enough. edited post with an example.let me know if any further clarification is required.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you could probably take advantage of the "Pimping" pattern to go back and forth between the two. Here's a chunk of stuff that I use in my application. I only convert one way, but you can see how with another implicit, you can implement the logic to go back to the original/your format.

```scala
// implicits for pimping 
implicit def pimpUser(user: User) = PimpedUser(user)
implicit def pimpLimitedViewUser(user: LimitedViewUser) = PimpedLimitedViewUser(user)

@entity
case class User(@serializer(classOf[UUIDOptionSerializer]) @id @column(name = "id") override val id: Option[UUID] = None,
                @serializer(classOf[DateOptionSerializer]) @column(name = "created_on") override val createdOn: Option[Date] = None,
                @serializer(classOf[DateOptionSerializer]) @column(name = "modified_on") override val modifiedOn: Option[Date] = None,
                @serializer(classOf[StringOptionSerializer]) @column(name = "first_name") firstName: Option[String] = None,
                @serializer(classOf[StringOptionSerializer]) @column(name = "last_name") lastName: Option[String] = None,
                @serializer(classOf[StringOptionSerializer]) @column(name = "email_address") emailAddress: Option[String] = None,
                @serializer(classOf[StringOptionSerializer]) @column(name = "password_salt") passwordSalt: Option[String] = None,
                @serializer(classOf[StringOptionSerializer]) @column(name = "password_hash") passwordHash: Option[String] = None,
                @serializer(classOf[IntOptionSerializer]) @column(name = "extension") extension: Option[Int] = None,
                devices: Set[Device] = Set.empty,
                @serializer(classOf[RingModeSerializer]) @column(name = "ring_mode") ringMode: RingMode = Waterfall) extends IdBaseEntity[UUID] {
  def this() = this(None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, Set.empty[Device], Waterfall)

  override def equals(other: Any): Boolean =
    other match {
      case that: User => (that canEqual this) && (this.id match {
        case Some(uuid) => that.id match {
          case Some(thatUuid) => uuid == thatUuid
          case None => false
        }
        case None => false
      })
      case _ => false
    }

  override def hashCode: Int = this.id match {
    case Some(uuid) => 41 * (41 + uuid.hashCode())
    case None => super.hashCode
  }

  override def canEqual(other: Any): Boolean = other.isInstanceOf[User]

  def asAvailable: User = {
    User.devices.set(this)(devices.map(_.asAvailable))
  }

  def asUnavailable: User = {
    User.devices.set(this)(devices.map(_.asUnavailable))
  }
}

object User {
  implicit val userIso = Iso.hlist(User.apply _, User.unapply _)

  val id = Lens[User] >> _0
  val createdOn = Lens[User] >> _1
  val modifiedOn = Lens[User] >> _2
  val firstName = Lens[User] >> _3
  val lastName = Lens[User] >> _4
  val emailAddress = Lens[User] >> _5
  val passwordSalt = Lens[User] >> _6
  val passwordHash = Lens[User] >> _7
  val extension = Lens[User] >> _8
  val devices = Lens[User] >> _9
  val ringMode = Lens[User] >> _10
}

case class LimitedViewUser(id: Option[UUID], createdOn: Option[Date], modifiedOn: Option[Date], firstName: Option[String], lastName: Option[String]) {
  def this(user: User) = this(user.id, user.createdOn, user.modifiedOn, user.firstName, user.lastName)
}

case class PimpedUser(underlying: User) {
  def limited = LimitedViewUser(underlying)
}

case class PimpedLimitedViewUser(underlying: LimitedViewUser) {
  def normal = /* do something here to transform back to yours/the normal one */
}

// As long as those implicits are brought into scope, you will be able to do this:

val user: User = /* ... */
val limitedViewUser: LimitedViewUser = user.limited
val normalUser: User = limitedViewUser.normal
```